# What does it mean for a .swf file to be compressed?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, compression

I tried converting a .swf file into .avi through ffmpeg, and I got the error 'compressed swf format not supported'. How does a compressed .swf differ from an uncompressed .swf file? How do you specify which one you want to make, and is it even possible to? How would you decompress a compressed .swf and what should you expect to find? I googled a lot of these but I didn't manage to learn much from the bits and pieces I found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FFMpeg examines the swf file for am embedded FLV movie file and rips it out and converts it.  However most swfs are not just a simple embedded video file and contain all sorts of non-video elements including sprites, animation code, layers, etc.   FFMpeg is a video transcoder and simply has no way to parse through all that to output a video file: http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/296449-can-ffmpeg-convert-SWF-to-FLV

What could probably work a lot better is a application designed to playback the swf file, and record the outputted frames as it is being recorded, or to use any of the 100's of apps out there for converting swf's to video.

SoThink generally makes great products in relation to handling swf formats: http://www.sothink.com/product/swftovideoconverter/

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer :). Do you know if SoThink can manage automatic conversion/run from a command line? I was going with ffmpeg because I could automate the entire conversion process with multiple video, so ideally I would need an equivalent replacement for it

Comment: SoThink generally does have commandline options available in most of there products, but I would give their sales team a call to get more info on this.   If you like my answer a upvote &/ acceptance would be nice.

Comment: Here is a commandline sdk swf to flv converer though: http://www.swfkits.com/swf-to-video-sdk/

Comment: Sorry, I had to make sure the solutions you gave me truly worked :P. I remember trying other pieces of software from Moyea before and they didn't work :)